# Is it possible to edit the elements of a json array to accomodate additional data/elements?

Tags: php, json

I'm retrieving data from a database and pushing it to arrays then use json_encode() to output in json format. I have ended up having the data in this format.

```
[
    {
        "category_id": "1",
        "category_name": "Construction Materials"
    },
    {
        "items": [
            {
                "id": "1",
                "item_name": "Wire Mesh",
                "price": "459",
                "image_url": null
            },
            {
                "id": "2",
                "item_name": "Cement",
                "price": "700",
                "image_url": null
            },
            {
                "id": "3",
                "item_name": "Barbed Wire",
                "price": "3000",
                "image_url": null
            },
            {
                "id": "4",
                "item_name": "Iron sheet",
                "price": "200",
                "image_url": null
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "category_id": "2",
        "category_name": "Plumbing"
    },
```

***Here is what I want to achieve:***

```
[
    {
        "category_id": "1",
        "category_name": "Construction Materials"
        "items": [
            {
                "id": "1",
                "item_name": "Wire Mesh",
                "price": "459",
                "image_url": null
            },
            {
                "id": "2",
                "item_name": "Cement",
                "price": "40",
                "image_url": null
            },
            {
                "id": "3",
                "item_name": "Barbed Wire",
                "price": "3000",
                "image_url": null
            },
            {
                "id": "4",
                "item_name": "Iron sheet",
                "price": "200",
                "image_url": null
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "category_id": "2",
        "category_name": "Plumbing"
    },
```

How can I achive this in php. Is it possible to edit the contents of the main array? how can I add "items" after "category_name"
Regards..

Comment: Yes, convert the JSON to a PHP Data Structure, [`json_decode()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) fiddle with that and then convert the PHP Data Structure back to JSON [`json_encode()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php)

Comment: Do not consider some complex text manipulation, ___there be dragons___

Comment: @RiggsFolly how? an example would help

Comment: Lets start by you showing us the code that built this array

Comment: @RiggsFolly ... **How to Train Your Dragon** #666  `preg_replace('~"\s*},\s*{\s*"items"~', "\",\n\t\"items\"", $)` 

Comment: @MarkusAO :) `Notice: Undefined variable: �` :) :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$array = json_decode($yourJson);
$arrayLength = count($array);
$finalArray = [];
for ($i=0; $i < $arrayLength; $i+=2) {
    $finalArray[] = $array[$i] + $array[$i + 1];
}
$backToJson = json_encode($finalArray);
```

Alternative to [Mattijs](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6658294/mattijs)'s answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
function get_first_property($object) {
    $properties = array_keys(get_object_vars($object));
    return reset($properties);
}
function object_merge($object1, $object2) {
    return (object) array_merge((array) $object1, (array) $object2);
}

// loop through each of the array objects
$previous_first_property = null;
foreach ($array as $i => $object) {
    $first_property = get_first_property($object);
    
    // merge if the 1st property is "items", and the previous 1st was "category_id"
    if ($first_property == "items" && $previous_first_property == "category_id") {
        $array[$i - 1] = object_merge($array[$i - 1], $array[$i]);
        unset($array[$i]);
    }
    
    $previous_first_property = $first_property;
}
```